# sinon deny a stub being called even though it was called

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, express, sinon

I'm using sinon to stub a function `res.status`, res.status is called in both unit test below, one pass and the other fail, I even debugged and went line by line and see function is being called yet sinon fails and say the function wasn't called.

this is controller that I'm testing (ActivityController.js)

```
exports.findActivity = (req, res) => {
  ActivityService.findActivity(req.params.id, req.user).then(result => {
    res.status(200).json({result: result})
  }).catch(err => {
    res.status(500).json({msg: err.message})
  })
}
```

and here are the unit tests, the first test pass fine yet the second test doesn't

```
    it('should return Activity obj with status 200', async () => {
      expectedResult = activity
      sinon.stub(ActivityService, 'findActivity').resolves(expectedResult)
      await ActivityController.findActivity(req, res)
      sinon.assert.calledWith(ActivityService.findActivity)
      expect(res.status.calledOnce).to.equal(true)
      sinon.assert.calledWith(res.status, 200)
    })
    it('should return status 500 on server error', async () => {
      sinon.stub(ActivityService, 'findActivity').rejects()
      await ActivityController.findActivity(req, res)
      sinon.assert.calledWith(ActivityService.findActivity, req.params.id, req.user)
      expect(res.status.calledOnce).to.equal(true)
      sinon.assert.calledWith(res.status, 500)
    })
```

I debuged the second unit test and see ActivityController go through catch and call  `res.status(500)` yet the unit test fails in `res.status.calledOnce`

Comment: could you share part of code on how you define `res` in the test?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that `expect(res.status.calledOnce).to.equal(true)` was called immediately before waiting for `sinon.assert.calledWith`.

putting `await` before `sinon.assert` fixed the problem.

so the correct code is

```
  it('should return status 500 on server error', async () => {
      sinon.stub(ActivityService, 'findActivity').rejects()
      await ActivityController.findActivity(req, res)
      await sinon.assert.calledWith(ActivityService.findActivity, req.params.id, req.user)
      expect(res.status.calledOnce).to.equal(true)
      sinon.assert.calledWith(res.status, 500)
    })
```

Comment: why is this necessary?

Answer (score 0):

Are you reseting the `res.status` stub in between each test? `res.calledOnce` might not be true since it might be called **more** than once.

Comment: Yup after each test I run `sinon.restore()` also I inspected res and callCount is set to 0 so sinon didn't even falg it as called